# Macro to convert military time to standard time

Tags: macros

I'm learning a little TeX.
The following code works fine. But I don't know how to add a leading zero for hour and for minute, if
each one of them is less than 10.

Thank you for your help.

This code works fine. The output:

The military time is: 1221
The standard time is: 20:21

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\setlength\parindent{0in}

\newcount\Hour
\newcount\Minute
\Hour=\time
\divide\Hour by 60
\Minute =\Hour
\multiply\Minute by 60
\advance\Minute by -\time
\Minute = -\Minute


\begin{document}

The military time is: \the\time\\
The standard time is: \the\Hour{:}\the\Minute

\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume by "military time", you mean GMT (Greenwich Mean Time)? And "standard time" is determined by the time zone you're in, right?

Comment: @Mico I would interpret "military time" differently; namely 24-hour clock.  So I think the OP needs to clarify meanings.

Comment: `\time` gives minutes since midnight (local time), so your assertion of military time = `\the\time` is not correct under any definition of "military time" that I am familiar with.

Comment: When writing the code, my time zone was 20:21pm. My code converted it to 2021. An other example. Military time: 0345. standard time is 5:45. This is the best I could offer for clarification. Oh, by the way just try this command alone: \the\time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While the definition of "military" time is unclear, the issue of single digit hours and minutes is resolved via `\ifnum...<10`  test:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\setlength\parindent{0in}

\newcount\Hour
\newcount\Minute
\Hour=\time
\divide\Hour by 60
\Minute =\Hour
\multiply\Minute by 60
\advance\Minute by -\time
\Minute = -\Minute
\def\tdhour{\ifnum\Hour<10 0\the\Hour\else\the\Hour\fi}
\def\tdmin{\ifnum\Minute<10 0\the\Minute\else\the\Minute\fi}

\begin{document}

The military time is: \the\time\\
The standard time is: \tdhour:\tdmin
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\td...` macros may be more simply written as

```
\def\tdhour{\ifnum\Hour<10 0\fi\the\Hour}
\def\tdmin{\ifnum\Minute<10 0\fi\the\Minute}
```

Comment: Steven B. Segletes- Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what's “military time”. When you start a TeX run, the internal counter `\time` is initialized with the number of minutes past midnight.

For instance, if I start a run of TeX, I see 1340, which corresponds to 22:20 (local time).

You don't need counters to get the time in hh:mm format, because the LaTeX kernel already has counters that hold the current hour and current minute, so you just have to wrap them in a command that adds a leading zero if the number is less than 10.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\printtime}{}
 {
  \rafiq_twodigits:n { \c_sys_hour_int }
  :
  \rafiq_twodigits:n { \c_sys_minute_int }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \rafiq_twodigits:n
 {
  \int_compare:nNnT { #1 } < { 10 } { 0 } % perhaps add a leading 0
  \int_to_arabic:n { #1 } % print the number
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Minutes past midnight: \the\time

Local time: \printtime

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. I'm still totally new to Tex, LaTeX, let alone expl.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is: how to print minutes in two digit form. I am using the `\Othe` macro which can be defined by:

```
\def\Othe#1{\ifnum#1<10 0\fi\the#1}
```

and used:

```
Time is \the\hours:\Othe\minutes.
```

If you are using OpTeX, then this calculation (based on \directlua) is ready to use, because it is OpTeX trick [0055](https://petr.olsak.net/optex/optex-tricks.html#dayw) with the auto-loaded macro `\sethours`. It sets the `\hours` and `\minutes` registers to appropriate values from the current `\time` register. And the `\Othe` macro is auto-loaded too. So, you can write only this:

```
\sethours

Minutes past midnight:: \the\time.

Local time: \the\hours:\Othe\minutes.

\bye
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is very confusing to me. As far as I know, you have American time (am, pm), European time (17:00) and military time (1700). So this means to answer your question in the title: you just need to remove a colon. The value given by `\the\time` is not military time, it's just the time in minutes since midnight.

To recreate this more simply (if that is what you want?), you can use

```
\usepackage{datetime2}

\DTMnewtimestyle{customtimestyle}{%
  \renewcommand{\DTMdisplaytime}[3]{
    #1:#2
  }
}

\DTMsettimestyle{customtimestyle}

\begin{document}

time: \DTMcurrenttime

\end{document}
```

In the `\renewcommand` block, the arguments `#1`, `#2` and `#3` give the hours, minutes and seconds respectively. So go wild!

output:

[image]